# looping for every row in a table in t-sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

How do i loop in  t-sql for every row the table has? I have a table, WorkOrder it has two columns: name, name2. Now what I want is the values for the name column, be appended on the name2 column.

So for example, I have this row:

```
name   |  name2
test   |  test2
```

I want the name column to be appended on the name2 column so that it looks like this for every row.

```
name   |  name2
test   |  test test2
```

How do i do that? thanks

another question:

what if the combination of both columns exceeded the character limit for that column? When that happens I would like to ignore that row, and continue updating the others

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? SQL Server or mysql?

Comment: You want to select it or update the table itself?

Comment: update the table itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply do this:

```
UPDATE WorkOrder 
SET name2=name1+' '+name2
```

Comment: @AedzMigraso: Yes, it will. You don't need to loop. BTW, you can add a `WHERE` clause if you need.

Comment: it worked. i have another question tho. what if the combination of both columns exceeded the character limit for that column? When that happens I would like to ignore that row, and continue updating the others